# Is it possible to join dynamic ? Depending on the content of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am using this join to retrieve rows from `tblChassis` where `temp.ChassisNumber` matches `ch.ChassisNumber`

While this works, it is slow.

The reason it is slow is the `like '%'`

```
select ...
from @TempTable temp
left join tblChassis ch on ch.ChassisNumber like '%' + temp.ChassisNumber + '%'
```

I have to use the `like` because sometimes I don't get the full values to search with.

How this works is, the user drops a list of `chassis numbers` on a form, and then the form goes to find the chassisnumbers in the table.  Sometimes there will be full chassisnumbers (length = 17) but sometimes they don't have that, and they only have a part. this part could be the last xx digits, or the first xx digits, or some digits in the middle.
And off course sometimes they have a mix.

So what I did is make a temp table `declare @TempTable (ChassisNumber varchar(17))` and I fill it with all the chassisnumbers that the user dropped on the form.

Then I can select from this table and join with all other tables I need.

```
declare @TempTable table(ChassisNumber varchar(17))

insert into @TempTable 
values ('WF0EXXTTREMG4210'),
       ('WF0JXXWPCHMB28874'),
       ('WF0JXXWPCHMB'),
       ('MB28874')
  
select ...
from @TempTable temp
left join tblChassis ch on ch.ChassisNumber like '%' + temp.ChassisNumber + '%'
```

So now I am trying to get the query to perform a little faster, and I wonder if there is a way to make the join dynamic, so I could use the `like` when the chassisnumber is not 17 digits, and use the `=` when the chassisnumber does has 17 digits.

When the join is `ch.ChassisNumber = temp.ChassisNumber` the query is so fast I cant even measure it.

Is something like that possible ?

For example this pseudocode (not working off course but to give the idea what I am looking for)

```
on case 
       when len(temp.ChassisNumber) = 17 
           then ch.ChassisNumber = temp.ChassisNumber
       else ch.ChassisNumber like '%' + temp.ChassisNumber + '%'
   end
```

**EDIT**

I guess I could first join on all rows from the temptable that have chassisnumbers with 17 digits, and then `union` that with a query for all others.

That would help but I am hoping on something better.

Comment: You *could* do some "wonky" logic that doesn't require dynamic SQL, but it would only work for a scalar value (i.e. when comparing to a scalar parameter). It won't help you with an `ON` clause between 2 columns. If you implemented a `CASE` expression like above, it would not be any more performant as the `CASE` expression itself would be non-SARGable.

Comment: What bit didn't you follow, @GuidoG ?

Comment: @Larnu That was before you edited your comment.

Comment: I would suggest you might try splitting this into two queries that you can union together with two temp tables, one containing only values with length 17 and the other the rest; you can then use the first with an inner join using equality. no way to tell if this will be better without trying as the second query will be using an index/table scan regardless.

Comment: @Stu Yes I also was thinking this. It would all depend off course, if there are just a few rows with less then 17 digits then I notice performance gain, but if half or more have less then 17 digits there is less performance gain. I think there is indeed no way around that

Comment: You could also just add a flag to your temp table to indicate the length of each value, and use that in your join criteria instead of using `len()`, ie `on (ch.ChassisNumber = temp.ChassisNumber and flag=1) or (<like comparision> and flag=0)`

Comment: @Stu Thank you, that is a good idea that will help with making my joins use less rows than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what [Stu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15332650/stu) says in there [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69193943/is-it-possible-to-join-dynanic-depending-on-the-content-of-a-column#comment122296551_69193943) has some legs, however, I'd add a little more to this. Although this is a table variable, I would suggest adding a computed column to said table, and then you can do something filtering like below. This means that *if* all the rows in the table have a length of `17` then the bottom query should be "glossed" over as the `WHERE` will filter out all the rows from the variable:

```sql
DECLARE @TableVariable table (ChassisNumber varchar(17),
                              ChassisNumberLen AS LEN(ChassisNumber) PERSISTED);

INSERT INTO @TableVariable (ChassisNumber)
VALUES ('WF0EXXTTREMG4210'),
       ('WF0JXXWPCHMB28874'),
       ('WF0JXXWPCHMB'),
       ('MB28874');

SELECT *
FROM @TableVariable;

SELECT {YourColumns}
FROM @TableVariable TV
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblChassis CH ON TV.ChassisNumber = CH.ChassisNumber
WHERE TV.ChassisNumberLen = 17
UNION ALL
SELECT {YourColumns}
FROM @TableVariable TV
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblChassis CH ON CH.ChassisNumber LIKE '%' + TV.ChassisNumber + '%'
WHERE TV.ChassisNumberLen < 17; --I assume they can't be longer than 17
```

Comment: This works nice, but is it not basically the same as Stu had suggested ? It is easier off course because thanks to the computed column I don't have to fill in the second column of the temp table myself

Comment: And  yes, a ChassisNumber can have a maximum length of 17

Comment: *"but is it not basically the same as Stu had suggested"* I do mention that it does use them as inspiration, @GuidoG , I just add a little extra logic.